# how can I come out of if block?

Tags: java, if-statement, controls

Consider this code sample.

This code just serves to explain my question.

```
boolean status = false;
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    if ( i == 4 ) { 
        System.out.println ( "Enter into first if" );
        if ( status == false ) {
               System.out.println ( "Enter into second if" );
               status = true;
               if ( status == true ) {
                    System.out.println ( "Enter into third if" );
                    //third if body
               }
               //second if body                             
        }
        //first if body
        System.out.println ( "Before exiting first if" );
    }
}
```

**All I want to do is come out from third if to first if.**

We know **break, continue** are there that can be used in **loops**. Can we achieve the same for the **blocks**?

Comment: And why not just change `if` statements?

Comment: It's rather unclear what it is you're trying to achieve. In this case, instead of asking how to escape an if, look at the actual issue and refactor your code to suit your needs.

Comment: Use a `switch` statement instead?

Comment: if you don't want above one, worst case use flag variables... ;)

Comment: Why is there a line where status is being set to true, then right after checking to see if status is true?

Comment: Why can't you use `else` ?

Comment: Do you want to break out of IF 3 & 2, so you continue executing the remainder of IF 1?

Comment: @xagyg Yeah, that is what I explained in the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can break to any block:

```
public class Bar {

  static void foo(boolean b) {
    foo: {
      if (b) {
        break foo;
      }
      System.out.println(b);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(true);
    foo(false);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
false
```

See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7) for more.

However, if you tried to deliver this code in one of my projects we would probably have words.

Answer (score 3):

Create a method that encapsulates if #2 and #3. Then `return` from inside of the #3 if block:

```
boolean status = false;
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    if ( i == 4 ) { 
        System.out.println ( "Enter into first if" );
        status = perform2ndAnd3rdIf(status);
        System.out.println ( "Before exiting first if" );
    }
}

private boolean perform2ndAnd3rdIf(boolean status) {
    if ( status == false ) {
        System.out.println ( "Enter into second if" );
        status = true;
        if ( status == true ) {
            System.out.println ( "Enter into third if" );
            return status;
            //third if body
        }
        //second if body                             
    }
    return status;
}
```

Using a method instead of a nested `if` block improves overall readability and the ability to understand your code. Instead of code comments, you should give that method a meaningful name (of course *not* <del>`perform2ndAnd3rdIf()`</del>).

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this:

```
mylabel:
boolean status = false;
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    if ( i == 4 ) { 
        System.out.println ( "Enter into first if" );
        if ( status == false ) {
               System.out.println ( "Enter into second if" );
               status = true;
               if ( status == true ) {
                    System.out.println ( "Enter into third if" );

                    break mylabel;

                    //third if body
               }
               //second if body                             
        }
        //first if body
        System.out.println ( "Before exiting first if" );
    }
}
```

but I think that you should refactor your code instead.

Comment: I think the OP wants the first if statement to continue executing - "All I want to do is come out from third if to first if." - which would mean you place *mylabel:* immediately before the second if (e.g. "mylabel: if (status == false)"), hence breaking out of the end of the second if, but I think we need the OP to clarify!

Comment: I placed the label randomly just to indicate how can it be done, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure of your requirement which you are trying to achieve by this.Put one more if condition after the third loop, and if the condition is satisfied only, execute the remaining portion of second loop.You can set this condition inside third if block.

Instead of all this, you can just switch to 'switch' which will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd introduce a second status flag to catch that innermost condition:

```
boolean secondStatus = false;
boolean status = false;
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    if ( i == 4 ) { 
        System.out.println ( "Enter into first if" );
        if ( status == false && secondStatus == false ) {
               System.out.println ( "Enter into second if" );
               status = true;
               if ( status == true ) {
                    System.out.println ( "Enter into third if" );
                    //third if body
                    secondStatus = true;
               } else {
                   //second if body
               }                           
        }
        //first if body
        System.out.println ( "Before exiting first if" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite, that doesn't beak out of the 3rd if. It just ignores the 2nd if in the next loop. This doesn't work if "//second if body" wouldn't be a comment but some line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the simple combination of `while` loop and `break` statement may help.

```
boolean status = false;
for ( int i = 0; i <= 5; i++ ) {
    if ( i == 4 ) { 
        System.out.println ( "Enter into first if" );
        while(True) {
            if ( status == false ) {
                System.out.println ( "Enter into second if" );
                status = true;
                if ( status == true ) {
                    System.out.println ( "Enter into third if" );
                    break;//The key statement
                    //third if body
                }
                //second if body                             
            }
            break;//Don't forget break while loop
        }          
        //first if body
        System.out.println ( "Before exiting first if" );
    }
}
```

Or you may use `try .. catch ..`.